# R: Ctree: Knowing path and add values

Tags: r

```
library("caret")
library("randomForest")
library("party")
library("tree")
library("rpart")
library("rpart.plot")
library("survAUC")
library("survival")
options(digits=4)    
survivalTree<-ctree(Surv(survData$user_age,survData$is_user_active)~.,data=survData)
plot(survivalTree)
```

survData looks like this: [image]

it has alot more rows. and a-g are some kind of indicators which are in the nodes. user age is how long is the user in the system and alive or not is, as it says, alive or not (in our system).

With the above commands i've created a survivel ctree which looks like this:
[image]

Now there are 7 leaves. I would like for each leaf, lets take the first leaf from the left for example: the variable n there is  n = 17. i would like to add for (1,2,3) 17. so in that iteration 1,2,3 = 17. in the 4th iteration we are in the 4th leaf (from the left), n = 7. there i would like to add to (1,7,8,9) the value 7. so now 1 = 17+7=24. 2,3 = 17. and 7,8,9 = 7.

My problem is that i cannot reach the nodes as Ctree doesnt have a data-structure. Desired output is somthing like this:

```
a = 5001
b = 2232
c = 7110
d = 534
e = 223
f = 17
g = 6512
```

where a-g are factors in the 1st column of a data.frame and thier values are the 2nd column of that data.frame

Comment: First of all, you should provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data and make sure to be explicit about which libraries/packages you are using. I'm also confused about exactly what the desired output is here. Perhaps you could be more explicit about the structure of what you are after.

Comment: Tell me if you need me to add anything else

Comment: Still no data for this ... or for that matter the other question you asking.

Comment: Never mind, i've solved this. But I got another question..How do I get the 'n' value in each terminal node? like in node 4 n = 17

Comment: That was the question I was looking at originally.